# Why my properties can't get the values from the query string?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the tag helpers as-route-propertyName in the view, in the action method the names are exactly the same and the attribute [FromQuery] is there in front of them and still there have null values. The model in the razor view has the values and there is no problem with it.

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-warning col-md-3 mt-3" asp-controller="Company" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-route-addressId="@Model.AddressId" asp-route-imageId="@Model.ImageId">Edit Details</a>
```

and action method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromForm]CompanyEditViewModel model, [FromRoute]string id ,[FromQuery]string addressId, [FromQuery]string imageId) 
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your action method from this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromForm]CompanyEditViewModel model, [FromRoute]string id ,[FromQuery]string addressId, [FromQuery]string imageId) 
{
    //...
}
```

to this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id ,string addressId, string imageId) 
{
    //...
}
```